# Complex formula in excel

Tags: excel

I need a solutions please.
I have a column with numbers and text in excel.
I want to calculate SUM of consecutive numbers without interrupting by text.

I have attached an example here: [demo excel document](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2BDE6C5D10A581D!9129&authkey=!ALQT8PabZUFzn9k&ithint=file%2Cxlsx)

I want to find a formula to calculate red numbers.

Comment: As you know SO is not **"Write code for me"** site. Please share your effort and we'll help you with the issues.

Comment: because I am bored... starting in row 1: `{=IF(ISNUMBER(B1)*NOT(ISNUMBER(B2)),SUM(INDEX(B:B,MAX((1-ISNUMBER($B$1:B1))*ROW($B$1:B1))):B1),"")}` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **D4** enter:

```
=IF(A5="text",SUM(B$1:B4)-SUM($D$1:D3),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

***Note:***

This technique produces a column of sums of blocks by adding **all** of column **B** and subtracting the previous blocks recorded in column **D**.

**EDIT#1:**

If the texts are also in column **B**, then in **D4**:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(B5)),SUM(B$1:B4)-SUM($D$1:D3),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: what if in cell is not written "text" but different words ?

Comment: @JürgenKruja    then I would use `=IF(A5<>"",SUM(B$1:B4)-SUM($D$1:D3),"")`

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @garys-student sorry for disturbing again, what if the text is in the same column with numbers ?

Comment: I do this: `=IF(ISNUMBER(B5),"",SUM(B$1:B4)-SUM($D$1:D3))`